# CSS issue in vs code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I'm new in VS Code and I'm trying to figure out what went wrong here because css won't work for me. The link is good because it opens with click + ctrl. Both files are in the same folder. So why isn't it working?

[image]

Edit saved:

[image]

Comment: Have you saved the document? There appears to be unsaved changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you didn't save `index.html`. See the round dot? It means it's not saved.

[image]

Your code seems fine. Also, it's always better to use a browser than using built in preview.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I save it now and nothing happen :(

Comment: @Evela Did you try using a browser to open it up? Also, try refreshing the preview.

Comment: It's working on the website but when I refresh preview nothing change.... and honestly, I would prefer it to work here

Comment: @Evela That's not the right place to get your stuff working. VS Code is just a simple tool. But it doesn't really support all these features. Maybe I can suggest you Live Server + AutoSave, which will actually show your changes, right after you edit the code. Maybe you're looking for something like [CodeSandbox: Online Code Editor and IDE for Rapid Web Development](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Ohh ok :( I'll check CodeSandBox thank you!

Comment: @Evela It'll be really good. Check it out. I use it for React JS...

Answer (score 0):

Use an browser and save your files changes for see your proyect.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's working on the website but why not in VS Code? What do I have to do to make it work here?

Comment: Probably that viewer does not support some CSS and HTML features. I recommend you use a live preview extension so that visual studio works as you wish. Search the market for visual studio code.

Comment: if you have any other questions feel free to contact me :P

Answer (score 0):

Save file and try opening it with a browser. I always prefer browser to test a file. Sometimes 2 browsers if it has a problem. I suggest you to use sublime text 3 or notepad ++ with vs code because it can save you from a lot of headaches. :)